Parsing our XML data from a field
I'm new with extracting data point from XML with SNowflake.
I'm looking for help in extracting data from the following example:
<MainText>
  <subtext1>
    <Amount>555.02</Amount>
  </subtext>
  <subtext2>  
    <Address>4646 20th Ave</Adress>
  </subtext2>
</MainText>

I want to be able to extract the '4646 20th Ave' data point.
So far I have the following:
cast(GET(XMLGET(XMLGET((PARSE_XML(RAW_XML),'MainText'),'subtext2')'@Address') as varchar)

Any Ideas?

select
    parse_xml(raw_xml) as xml,
    xmlget(xml,'subtext2') as st2,
    xmlget(st2,'Address') as ad,
    ad['$']
from values
  ('<MainText><subtext1><Amount>555.02</Amount></subtext1><subtext2><Address>4646 20th Ave</Address></subtext2></MainText>') 
    as t(raw_xml);

is a deconstructed way, and the one liner:
select
    xmlget(xmlget(parse_xml(raw_xml),'subtext2'), 'Address')['$'] as address
from values
  ('<MainText><subtext1><Amount>555.02</Amount></subtext1><subtext2><Address>4646 20th Ave</Address></subtext2></MainText>') 
    as t(raw_xml);


and to cast to string/text
xmlget(xmlget(parse_xml(raw_xml),'subtext2'), 'Address')['$']::text as address

